# Is there a way to convert millisecondsSinceEpoch to date,month year format in DateFormat?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to millisecondsSinceEpoch `1619451874928` to dd-MM-YYYY format in flutter. Is there any method that does that?

How to convert eg. `1619451874928` to `27 March 2021`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  final dateTime = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(1619451874928);
  final dateTimeString = DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(dateTime);
  print(dateTimeString);
  final dateTimeStringLong = DateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy").format(dateTime);
  print(dateTimeStringLong);
}
```

dateTimeString will be in format you requested, i.e. "dd-MM-yyyy". Hovever in order to get date in format of "27 March 2021", you should use following pattern
"dd MMMM yyyy".

Please note that you should also include and import package 'package:intl/intl.dart'

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
DateFormat("dd MM yyyy").format((DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(1619451874928)));
```

Comment: "dd-MM-YYYY" is not valid pattern, it should be "dd-MM-yyyy"